# Not able to launch "Microsoft Edge" browser in windows 10 using selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am using selenium webdriver c# automation. And i have to run automation on windows 10 machine for "Microsoft Edge" browser. Please let me know how to launch "Microsoft Edge" in widnows 10 using c# selenium webdriver.

I have used below code to launch but its launching IE 11.

Answer (score 2):

1. Do you have the [Microsoft Webdriver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48212)? This is used for the new Edge Browser
2. Is your Selenium Webdriver  version 2.47 ? Selenium adds Edge support with 2.47
3. And try

   ```
   IWebdriver driver = new EdgeDriver(serverPath, options);
   ```

   For more [Information and Examples](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/)

Comment: No i dont have Microsoft Wbdriver ..please give me download link of that.

Comment: also give me 2.47 c# driver link to download

Comment: @simond updated the broken webdriver link and did you install Selenium via Nuget? If not http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ is the link for the file

Comment: Why the IE Driver? I thought you wanted to use Edge?

Comment: oh sorry ..yes i want to use edge

Comment: @simond Then Download the Microsoft Webdriver. And look at the link with the example.

Comment: and i have installed and updated dll of 2.47 ...is the selenium webdriver and microsoft driver are same??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84797/discussion-between-lzypanda-and-simond).

Comment: Did you end up finding out what the issue/solution was? I'm having a similar problem.